# Model outcome = mortality (count), exposure = climate (continuous), Rstudio

Tags: r, poisson

I have ran Poisson distribution model with quasi Poisson error in Rstudio

```
glm(formula = MI ~ corr_data$Temperature + corr_data$Humidity + 
corr_data$Sun + corr_data$Rain, family = quasipoisson(), 
data = corr_data)

Deviance Residuals: 
Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-3.5323  -1.1149  -0.1346   0.8591   3.2585  

Coefficients:
                    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)            3.9494713  1.2068332   3.273  0.00144 **
corr_data$Temperature -0.0281248  0.0144238  -1.950  0.05381 . 
corr_data$Humidity    -0.0099800  0.0144047  -0.693  0.48992   
corr_data$Sun         -0.0767811  0.0414464  -1.853  0.06670 . 
corr_data$Rain        -0.0003076  0.0004211  -0.731  0.46662   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for quasipoisson family taken to be 1.873611)

Null deviance: 249.16  on 111  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 206.36  on 107  degrees of freedom
(24 observations deleted due to missingness)
```

I have read that the dispersion parameter should be ideally close to 1

I have some zero values in my cumulative rainfall measures.

How best to I go about finding the appropriate model?

I next tried negative binomial

```
Call:
glm.nb(formula = Incidence ~ Humidity + Sun + Rain, data = corr_data, 
init.theta = 22.16822882, link = log)

Deviance Residuals: 
 Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-2.53274  -0.85380  -0.08705   0.73230   2.48643  

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)  1.3626266  1.0970701   1.242   0.2142  
Humidity     0.0111537  0.0124768   0.894   0.3713  
 Sun         -0.0295395  0.0345469  -0.855   0.3925  
 Rain        -0.0006170  0.0003007  -2.052   0.0402 *
---
 Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for Negative Binomial(22.1682) family taken to be 1)

Null deviance: 120.09  on 111  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 113.57  on 108  degrees of freedom
(24 observations deleted due to missingness)
AIC: 578.3

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 1


          Theta:  22.2 
      Std. Err.:  11.8 

 2 x log-likelihood:  -568.299
```

Any advice would be very much appreciated.  I am new to R and to modelling!